# Connection refused to REST Django

Tags: django, rest, reactjs

I have a problem with access to my REST Django data. As u already understand, I have a Django app whith standart REST localhost with my data. My another application, which i made in ReactJS, got Json file with data using axios throught standart GET ajax request. Now i wanna to connect to my React app from another computer at the same network and it's go easily using `http://ip4:3000`. But in that way i can't get data from REST page which i have on my `localhost:8000`. I try to get data from terminal in the same way using `ip + localhostport`, but i always got an error :

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 106.120.89.142 port 8000: Connection refused

I can't do it using browser to, someone know solution for that?

Comment: Make sure that you have opened port 8000 in machine that runs your django app and both machines are in same network. Try telnet ting to the port using `telnet 106.120.89.142 8000`

Comment: If you juste want to access your app from another computer but don't want to bother with network configuration [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) is pretty nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start a django development server with

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

this will open your port and make django app to be visible from outside world.

Comment: And then i should add my IP to my settings.py ALLOWED_HOSTS. Ty man.